# How to use angular to refresh a div?

Tags: angularjs, refresh

when I click the "Refresh" or the src,I want to only refresh the following "div" and another div ,not the whole html.
How do use angularjs to do?

```
<div>
<img   alt="Refresh" src="/Captcha/[[.CaptchaId]]/" /><span>Refresh</span>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You bind your img src to your scope and add a `ng-click` handler to your img tag to handle click event, and change the binded value accordingly

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.url = "old.png";
  $scope.refresh = function() {
    $scope.url = "new.png";
  };
})
```

and your html:

```
<img src="{{url}}" ng-click="refresh()">Refresh</img>
```

Comment: if the src has a init value,now how to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to prevent default handler:

html:

```
<img src="{{url}}" ng-click="saveUser($event)">Refresh</img>
```

js:

```
$scope.saveUser = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // your code
}
```